# Incorrect MIME type for GET requests

Tags: scala, jetty, lift

I've been using the Lift Web Framework as a REST only service for quite a while, but I need to use it as a stand alone tool now.

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
  <head>
      <script data-lift="with-resource-id" src="/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <h2>Welcome to your project!</h2>
  <p><lift:helloWorld.howdy /></p>
</lift:surround>
```

I have the above very basic Lift template. The problem is when I view it in the browser something is adding an `<?xml>` DOCTYPE and the browser defaults to interpreting the resource as XML instead of plain HTML.

How do I tell Jetty/Lift that my static file is HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be using the XHTML doctype. In your `Boot.scala` file, you may want to try adding:

```
LiftRules.htmlProperties.default.set((r: Req) =>
  new Html5Properties(r.userAgent))
```

That should set your application to use HTML5, and should [turn off](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/2.4/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/HtmlProperties.scala#L330) adding the `<?xml...` encoding header.

Also, as @VasyaNovikov mentioned, the `lift:` prefixed tags are an older construct (even though a lot of documentation still mentions them). They still work but will have some issues with HTML5. It is recommended to use either of the equivalent forms:

Original:

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">...</lift:surround>
```

HTML5:

```
<span data-lift="surround?with=default;at=content"></span>    
<span class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content"></span>
```

If you want to use the `lift:` variety, the biggest issue you'll find is that in HTML5 the tags and attributes are converted to lowercase, so `<lift:helloWorld.howdy />` will be interpreted as `<lift:helloworld.howdy />`, and Lift will not find the snippet. Using `<span data-lift="helloWorld.howdy"></span>` should allow you to work around that.

Comment: Oh, sorry- yes, I meant `Boot.scala`. I just updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding the  header will help?

```
<html>
<head>...
```

Example:
https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/blob/master/scala_29/lift_basic/src/main/webapp/index.html

In general, you use a very old approach to templates, with custom tags `<lift:surround>`, `<lift:helloWorld>` and such. Where did you get them? I suggest to use the new template style like in the link I posted.